# ES6: Get value from an array based on values of another array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

`enter code here`**JS Code:**

```
DOCUMENTS = [{
      name: 'I551Indicator',
      text: ‘School Document’,
   },
   {
      name: 'I553Indicator',
      text: ‘Birth Certificate’,
   }
];

User_Selected_Documents = [{
   I551Indicator: false,
   I553Indicator: true
}];
```

From the `DOCUMENTS` array, I have to display the text of the document for the keys whose value is true in `User_Selected_Documents` array.

I tried the below, seems to get the text

```
const test = DOCUMENTS.map(doc => doc).map(doc => doc.name).filter(DOCUMENTS.map(selctedDocuments));
```

trying to find the key whose value is true from `User_Selected_Documents.filter(selectedDocument => Object.values(selectedDocument) === true)`

dosen't seem to work.

EXPECTED RESULT: I this case it is `Birth Certificate` since `I553Indicator` is `true`

Comment: Please can you show the specific piece of code that you attempted and that's not working.

Comment: @Zuckerberg - added my code that I tried. Also trying to chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `filter` and then `map`. Below code works:

```js
DOCUMENTS = [{
      name: 'I551Indicator',
      text: 'School Document',
   },
   {
      name: 'I553Indicator',
      text: 'Birth Certificate',
   }
];

User_Selected_Documents = [{
   I551Indicator: false,
   I553Indicator: true
}];

const result = DOCUMENTS.filter(x => User_Selected_Documents[0][x.name]).map(x => x.text)

console.log(result[0])
```

Comment: it returns the whole object. How do I get just the `text` from `DOCUMENTS`. I this case it is `Birth Certificate` since `I553Indicator `is `true`

Comment: @dragonfly edited my post... now result will be `Birth Certificate`